# Convert application with multiple @StreamListener to use multiple Consumer

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I am attempting to convert application that are using the deprecated @StreamListener annotations to use the recommended Consumer functional implementations.   For application that are listening to only a single topic the conversion has been easy.   Where I am having a problem is when an application is listening to two different topics using two @StreamListener annotations.   If I converted each to Consumer bean neither bean gets registered.   I have tried to separate the Consumer beans into separate classes but that does not seem to make any difference.

For clarification these are the binding properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic1-in-0.destination=data_extractor_1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic1-in-0.group=data_extractor_1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic2-in-0.destination=data_extractor_2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic2-in-0.group=data_extractor_2
```

These are the defined Consumer beans

```
@Bean
public Consumer<DataExtractionMessage> dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic1() {
    return incomingMessage -> {
        log.info("dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic1 received {}", incomingMessage);
    };
}

@Bean
public Consumer<DataExtractionMessage> dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic2() {
    return incomingMessage -> {
        log.info("dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic2 received {}", incomingMessage);
    };
}
```

Is there a limitation that an application can only have one bound Consumer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is that if there is more than one Consumer bean all must be explicitly identified in the property spring.cloud.stream.function.definition.   I this particular case the property should be entered as:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic1;dataExtractionMessageConsumerTopic2
```